# C++ issue with opening input and output using variables error

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling

I'm having errors when I try to compile my program. The program is supposed to merge two sorted arrays. So say one array has an input of 2 3 4 4 5 9 while the second array has 1 4 5 8 9 11 12 13, the output file will have 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 8 9 9 11 11 12 13. My issue is when I try to compile the program I get these errors concerning the opening of the input and output file.
Errors:

```
hwork.cpp:56:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)’
 out.open(s);

hwork.cpp:16:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)’
 in.open(s);
```

I posted my program code below, can someone explain what I am doing wrong. Thank you!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int readSortedArray(int arr[], string str)
{

    std::ifstream in;
    string s;

    cout << "\nEnter name of " << str << " input file name with extension, eg: input.txt \n";
    cin >> s;

    in.open(s);

    if (in.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            in >> arr[i];
        }
        in.close();
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::ofstream out;
    string s;

    int array1[20], array2[20], array3[40], okay;

    okay = readSortedArray(array1, "first");
    if (!okay) {
        cout << "Failed to open first input file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    okay = readSortedArray(array2, "second");
    if (!okay) {
        cout << "Failed to open second input file\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "\nEnter output file name with extension, eg: output.txt \n";
    cin >> s;

    out.open(s);
    if (out.is_open()) {

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < 20 && j < 20) {
            if (array1[i] < array2[j]) {
                array3[k] = array1[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                array3[k] = array2[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while (j < 20) {
            array3[k] = array2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        while (i < 20) {
            array3[k] = array1[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            if (i)
                out << " ";
            out << array3[i];
        }

        out.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed to open output file\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use  in.open( s.c_str() );

Comment: You must have an old compiler or you are not using c++11 (2011 standard) or better.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow jeez thank you, that was the issue.

Comment: What you are trying to do will work in C++11 or more recent standards. Consult your development tools for how to select different C++ Standards. Based on the error message, adding `-std=C++11` to the command line should work.

Comment: And with C++ everyone is pretty much always a beginner. New, language-changing stuff shows up just about every three years.